# Connect to MySQL from Python in Google Cloud

Tags: python, mysql

Basically the question is how to connect to MySQL database from Python in Google Cloud, *but not that way*. Yes, I know about [`google.cloud.sql.connector`](https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/main/samples/notebooks/mysql_python_connector.ipynb) approach, and that works fine.

The question is if there is a possibility to put a Python application written using the standard `mysql.connector` library into Google Cloud without the necessity of changing the source code?

Other way around, is there a possibility to execute the code suitable in Google Cloud locally?

Putting both together: I am looking for an approach where the relevant data (server, port, username, password, database; is there anything else?) are stored in a config file, and both locally and in the cloud we just need to setup these parameters, without the necessity to change the source code itself.

Comment: You can connect via a traditional mysql connector to a google clod mysql instancd, too. However, in that case ypu need to configure IAM, routing, SSL, etc. yourself. Google's cloud sql connector takes care of most of these.